# How to use Twisted Web static.File resource without cache?

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

I am using the Twisted Web static.File resource for the static part of the web server.

For development I would like to be able to add new file or to modify the current static files without having the restart the Twisted web server.

I am looking at the source code for static.File at getChild method and I can not see how the resources are cached:
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/web/static.py#L280

From my understanding getChild method is returning a new resource at each call.
Any help in creating a non-cached static.File resource is much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`twisted.web.static.File` serves straight from the filesystem.  It does not have a cache.  Your web browser probably has a cache, though.

Comment: Many thanks for this confirmation. I found out that the problem was me. I was just looking at the wrong folder.